# Copied a View to a project with Navigation Controller - Frame for "Image View" will be different at run time

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

Probably a simple question for experienced Xcode 5 interface builder users, but it is difficult to find the answer on Google:

I have [an app for iPhone](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyFacebook), which doesn't use a navigation controller (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW0rA.png)):

[image: xcode screenshot]

The view scene on the very right side has an image view and 5 labels underneath it - to display user details:

[image: app screenshot]

Then I have created [another iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth) and copied that "details" view to it (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G415L.png)):

[image: xcode screenshot]

And now a warning is shown by Xcode 5.0.2:

> Frame for "Image View" will be different at run time.

Is it because some space on the top of the view will be occupied by the navigation bar?

And how to fix it please?

I've tried clicking the **[-o-]** icon, but instead of resolving my layout issue it has messed the whole layout (the labels jumped to the left).

Also I've tried setting checkboxes on the right side in the Xcode Attributes Inspector, but haven't be able to find any good combination there (and I am not sure what "inferred" means in Xcode context).

**UPDATE:**

Ossir's suggestion has worked for me, thank you.

I'm posting a new screenshot (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHQg1.png)) in case anybody have more improvement suggestions:

[image: xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the `UIImageView` and click **[-o-]** icon, then choose **Reset To Suggested Constraints** menu item.
**Simulated metrics** section does nothing in the runtime, it only us to figure out how layout will look like before compiling.

Also there is one more (better) approach, but you have to analyse what constraints `UIImageView` has and change them accordingly for new layout (with added nav bar). You can try to post screenshot with those constraints here, so we can help you to figure out what happened. Go to **Size Inspector** in right panel and show us **Constraints** section.

**UPDATE**

Your constraints force `UIImageView` to have the same horizontal align as labels below have and the same width. Plus you have constraints for fixed vertical space from the topmost label and navigation bar, width of `UIImageView` depends on available space between nav bar and labels. I think it's good solution for current layout (without scrolling), because everything will fit into the screen for both 3.5" and 4" inch displays. In case you want different behaviour let me know in a comments.

Answer (score 22):

I found that unchecking the Adjust Scroll View Insets checkbox for the navigation controller in question cleared the warning

[image: Adjust Scroll View Insets]

Comment: Any idea why that helped?

Comment: No, sorry, would love an adequate explanation. I have also noticed that the issue can re-appear and checking / unchecking clears it.

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same warnings in Xcode version 8.0 Swift 3.0. The warning went away after I checked and unchecked the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" option. Note: they were not checked at the start like in the comment above, so it may clarify for those who have this same warning.

Check/Uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" option.

[image]

Comment: Checking / unchecking 'Adjust scroll View Insets' will clear this in Xcode 8 / Swift 3, but only temporarily.  They will return after you restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you run your app on a 3.5" screen while you've been designing it for a 4" screen in interface builder.
You should set all missing constraints so that autolayout 'knows' how to lay out your image view and labels.

I would set a fixed height for the labels and a variable height for the image view. Then set the content mode of your image view to "aspect fill" (note that in this case you'll loose a part of the image instead of having gray stripes on the left and right sides).

Comment: +1 thank you! How do you set a "variable height" for a subview? I don't see such an option in Xcode Size Inspector, when I click the image view: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eHQg1.png

Comment: In the layout configuration shown in that screenshot the height of the UIImageView is already variable. If you define a fixed space between the top of the view and the image view AND all the elements under the image view have also a fixed height then the image view will grow to fill the remaining space.