# Warning frame for "Navigation bar" will be different at run time appears in Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode8

Before I've upgraded to `Xcode 8` I haven't seen this error in such case. I have different Navigation Controllers. For all of them I see an error `Frame for "Navigation bar" will be different at the run time. Navigation bar "Expected: width=384, Actual: width=375`. In reality these Navigation Controllers doesn't have `Navigation bar`. `Navigation bar` exists for subviews. Anyway I could solve it by tick and untick the checkbox `Shows navigation bar` in `Attributes inspector`. But unfortunately every time I reopen `Main.storyboard` this warning appears again. Also if I click on yellow triangle and then on update frames nothing happen.

[image]

Comment: Same issue here confirmed. None of the suggested resolutions fix the problem.

Comment: @GregP please check my solution and reply

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad   please check my solution and reply

Comment: Filed rdar://28844288. Feel free to dupe http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4985464104681472

Comment: This is my last warning that is bugging me after updating my project.

Comment: This happened to me while changing the navigation-bar style property in IB to Black

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Warning will disappear if you change the property "Simulated Size"  to "Freeform".

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve problem. Close Xcode and Open again the issue will come again.

Comment: @AshishKakkad And there is! Used to do the same and become normal, but then again it's a warning there...

Comment: This is bugging the hell out of me.. I just tried this, and this does remove warning *temporarily*. You can always switch Simulated Size back and forth to remove the warning when it does come back. Super. Annoying.

Comment: Only a temporary fix - this is not the answer.

Comment: You may still see this error if you don't manually change the size to the suggested.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks @Kai

Comment: Either change this Simulated Size (and back to 'Inferred' or whatever) or _"toggling Adjust Scrollview Insets on/off"_. Both will cause Storyboard to remove its `misplaced="YES"`. This is an Xcode bug, and this fix is a force-refresh kind. **Taken from @buildsucceeded answer.**

Comment: @bauerMusic what do you mean a force refresh kind?

Comment: @MobileBloke By force-refresh I meant that it will cause the Storyboard view to rewrite (refresh) the params, re-evaluate and remove the warning. It's really a refresh, force was only meant that it didn't do it automatically by itself (as it should) and needed some manual arbitrary change.

Comment: Makes sense - I thought there was a magic button . I noticed that storyboard is taking longer to load since this bug started appearing .. you seeing this too ?

Comment: Xcode is a sea of unsolved bugs that continue there, marinating, forever.

Comment: I could only make it go away permanently (even after restart) by using the width that appeared in the warning, as the value in the Freeform option.

Answer (score 35):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39014669/395295) you can fix this by toggling Adjust Scrollview Insets on/off.

Comment: Wow, and (checking git) literally all that happens when you do this is that `misplaced="YES"` gets removed. :/

Comment: That fixes it until the next time your close and reopen the project. Not a complete fix.

Answer (score 15):

I have changed from View as: iPhone 6S to iPhone 5S, then changed back to iPhone 6S, and Xcode did all the changes to remove the warning.

Comment: This worked for a short time- then after Xcode procesed it again - the same thing happened and the warning re-occured.  Is this still working for you on latest Xcode?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me at Xcode 8.3.1
After restarting Xcode, it would still work.

[image]

1. Select Navigation Controller

[image]

2. Go to Show the Size Inspector

[image]

3. Change Simulated Size to Freeform

[image]

4. Change Simulated Size back to Fixed

[image]

5. Then the warnings disappear.

[image]

Comment: Any idea why this would have worked and not "Update frames" button?

Comment: @guoc, bro could you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375778/add-navigation-bar-in-uicollectionview-in-swift-4-ios-11 ?

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround just to get rid of the annoying warning I have been editing Main.storyboard manually by removing 'misplaced' in:

```
<navigationBar key="navigationBar" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" misplaced="YES" translucent="NO" id="Os1-Xh-7XN">
```

A hack but it is nice to have zero warnings rather than 1 :)

Comment: Will I have to add this back later? I don't really care what my navigation Controller looks like so long as I don't have warnings. It's kind of funny. The storyboard recognizes the warning for a split second and then it goes away when you enter the storyboard this way.

Comment: I did the same thing and then don't touch the storyboard again. Everything works well.

Comment: PRoblem is that when you reload it comes back... anyone else noticing that it takes a long time to load the storyboard with the spinner running when this error occurs?

Answer (score 6):

Click "View As" at the bottom left of your storyboard and choose a different device size, then click it again and swap back to the device size you started with. This worked for me.

Comment: it also just temp fixing it for me

Answer (score 3):

Until Xcode 8 is patched, you can set the "View as:" option to "iPhone SE" to eliminate the warning. Not ideal, but works for now.

Comment: I am USING SE .. but still Warning

Comment: Yeah, I know. But they do go away whenever you switch that selection to something else. Nowadays, I start with 7, switch to SE, then back to 7 to clear these warnings. Or just leave them, and just not check `misplaced` properties in when commiting changes.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above suggestions but it didn't seem to work.  I think it might be a more serious bug.

I have logged a bug with Apple Bug Reporter( link: https://bugreport.apple.com/logon) - if you want to do the same, then please reference bug : `31355220` so that Apple can tie it together.  The more people that report it - the more information they will have to fix this annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the issue completely by setting the simulated size of the view controller to freeform and then setting the width from 375 to 320.

Comment: You only need to set it only on the view controllers that have no parents (root view controller + maybe more, depending on what you have in your storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, here's what I did to fix:

Expand the error information and click on the warning detail. Xcode should then automatically open the dimension/position settings. Replace the current value with the value suggested in the warning details.

[image]

Basically, make sure that the size in your runtime is the same as the size you have specified in the size inspector.

You can also click the icon beside the image you posted (the yellow triangle with white circle. Sometimes, its a red circle icon) then there will be options to automatically fix/adjust the issues.

[image]

I chose the update constraints option then adjusted the new constraints accordingly.

Comment: Does not work in this situation.  The X/Y/Width/Height fields for the Navigation Bar are all grayed-out/uneditable.

Comment: @Ian Hmmm… I think I just ended up editing the xib so that the numbers matched up.

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was that i was hiding the bottom bar on push (using IB checkbox).

i had to select 'none' in 'bottom bar' option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like I've fixed the issue. Here's what I did.

Select update frames like normal. Open a different file and then click back on the storyboard file. If that doesn't work then restart Xcode. It looks like it was updating internally but the interface builder UI was stuck as it sometimes gets.

Comment: After reopening of XCode this warning actually disappears, but if I open any file in the project an the again open `main.storyboard` these warnings appear again

Answer (score 0):

Please change your device Preview in xcode for View controller and compile and check for warnings...

Xcode 8 is bit buggy, Interface builder reset its with random no which affects all contained views.
Try changing your preview device.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12

I think this problem is mostly because the width of device preview is different per various devices. E.g. iPhone 12 and iPhone 11 have different screenWidth. If you set a fix value on width of some view and give it some constraints, then it may not adopt your current previewed iPhone's screen width, so it complained "different size in run time".

And for me, I set an UIView and ImageView's width & height as fixed value in size inspector with iPhone 11 preview. And gives it also fixed 10 points leading and trailing constraints in IB. Then it complained if I switch to iPhone 12 preview.

To fix it, I select the viewController and chose "Update Frames". Then it looks better but Xcode still complain one conflict constraint after the change. Eventually, I manually found and fix it in IB.