# Xcode 8 Issue : Frame for "Navigation Bar" will be different at run time

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

When we Embed your view controller in Navigation Controller. Then facing issue with navigation bar.

**Xcode 8 Issue : Frame for "Navigation Bar" will be different at run time.**

[image: Navigation Bar Image Issue]

Note : When we hide the navigation bar and show it again then issue gone away. And after when we open the storyboard then issue raise again.

Also I have tried to do as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621140/warning-frame-for-navigation-bar-will-be-different-at-the-run-time-appears-in) given here. It's not working. If you open storyboard again then this issue raise again.

*Same issue is there with Xcode 8.1*

How can we resolve this issue?

---

**This issue is resolved in Xcode 10.**

Comment: I think that issue is in Xcode 7 too ... don't bother about it too much

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 No, There is no issue like this in Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: I encounters same problem in Xcode 7 ...so I just mention it ... don't know much about exact version hough

Comment: try to clear and re add constraints after that embed view

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 In empty view also you will face this problem :D

Comment: this seems bug ... Xcode 8 is full of bugs :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Has no effect on how my app looks but I would like to get rid of those warnings

Comment: could you share sample project or at least add an screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: is it solved ? @AshishKakkad

Comment: @MayankPatel Not Yet. Let see in Xcode 8.2

Comment: Having the same problem in Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621140/warning-frame-for-navigation-bar-will-be-different-at-run-time-appears-in-xcod

Comment: @warisshams This link is already in question :)

Answer (score 17):

In View Controller's attribute you can see "Simulated Metrics". Change the "Size" attribute to "Freeform" instead of "Inferred". This will remove the warning.

Comment: Click on another file and then on your storyboard again - these warnings will come back (Xcode 8.2.1)

Comment: Close your xcode and open again , it comes back

Comment: @KunalGupta I observed that, Seems like a bug, not sure.

Comment: seems its a xcode 8 bug @Amanpreet

Comment: @KunalGupta Yes it will be. Because I searched a lot and all the solutions are temp.

Comment: Also you'll need to change the freeform width from `375` to `320`

Comment: I was able to get rid of the issue completely by setting the simulated size of the view controller to freeform and then setting the width from 375 to 320.