# Xcode 8 Frame for "Navigation Bar" will be different at run time error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Right after installing Xcode 8 I'm getting this error in my project for each `Navigation Bar`:

```
/Users/Amir_P/Desktop/example/ios/example/example/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard Frame for "Navigation Bar" will be different at run time.
```

I tried Update Frames, Update Constraints but nothing happened. How can I solve it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you to share your storyboard?

Comment: I've updated my post @Mozilla

Comment: Look to this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621140/warning-frame-for-navigation-bar-will-be-different-at-the-run-time-appears-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621140/warning-frame-for-navigation-bar-will-be-different-at-the-run-time-appears-in)

Comment: but as you can see I can't edit height and width @Mozilla

Comment: Try to set `Freeform` for _Simulated Size_ or _Simulated Metrics_

Comment: there is no `Freeform` in my options!only `Frame Rectangle` and `Alignment Rectangle` @Mozilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning will disappear if you change the property "Simulated Size" to "Freeform".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing storyboard 6 size device to iPhone SE it works to me

in xcode 7.3.1 my storyboard's all viewController size was 4 inch iphone device(320x568)

[image]