# Add Navigation Bar in UICollectionView in swift 4, iOS 11

Tags: uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, swift4, xcode9

After upgrading the iOS 11 and swift 4(Xcode 9), I got lots of UI problem. :( 
The most unsolvable problem is Navigation Problem. 
I **put the Navigation Bar in UICollectionView Controller**.
 Navigation bar height does not show properly and however I write the code.

I set navigation bar height "100". I write this code in ViewDidLoad().

```
  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        print("IOS 11 Screen")

        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,

        ]
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        let height: CGFloat = 100 //whatever height you want
        let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)


    } else {
        print("lower than IOS 11 Screen")
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

 collectionview?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 20)) <br>

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 100 //whatever height you want
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)

}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let height: CGFloat = 100 //whatever height you want
        let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
    }
```

However, I tried with this code. Nothing works for me.

[image]

I also tried to open the storyboard with source code view and I edit the height of Navigation bar. But, it also does not work.
Can anyone help me please? I have been trying to solve this problem since last two days.

Comment: I don't think you could adjust the height of Navigation Bar. instead, you could create a custom navigation bar, while cover it up on the one given by system.

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        print("IOS 11 Screen")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
        ]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true // added this line
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    } else {
        print("lower than IOS 11 Screen")
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let height: CGFloat = 100 //whatever height you want
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
}
```

Comment: I can solve this problem now bro. But I got another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376475/uinavigationbar-does-not-overlap-to-uicollectionview-in-swift-4 Could you please help me bro?

Comment: What's your solution? @MayPhyu

Comment: @antonio081014, I refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940352/how-to-increase-the-height-of-navigation-bar-in-xcode.   I add space to increase the height of Navigation bar bro

Comment: Yes bro @antonio081014, I got another problem bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376475/uinavigationbar-does-not-overlap-to-uicollectionview-in-swift-4 . Could you please take a look at?