# Expected: width=414 Actual: Width=375 warning in uitableviewcell for Xcode 9.x.x

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, xcode9

I am trying to resolve the `Expected: width=414 Actual: Width=375 warning in uitableviewcell for Xcode 9.x.x` but every time when I switch the device I am getting the same warning as you can see in pic.

[image]

I have gone through some of the solutions from [Warning frame for “Navigation bar” will be different at run time appears in XCode 8 Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621140/warning-frame-for-navigation-bar-will-be-different-at-run-time-appears-in-xcod) but no luck.

Comment: No answers for three years? c'mon